# Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - all models using find(params[:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I had my tests working (for the most part) and now all of the sudden they are all breaking.  All models fail with almost all tests - it seems to be fixture related:

```
  test_should_show_project                                       ERROR (3.19s)
Minitest::UnexpectedError:         ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Project with 'id'=980190962 [WHERE "projects"."account_id" = $1]
            app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:120:in `set_project'
            lib/jumpstart/lib/jumpstart/account_middleware.rb:32:in `call'
            test/controllers/projects_controller_test.rb:50:in `block in <class:ProjectsControllerTest>'
```

`set_project` is your standard:

```
  def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])

    # Uncomment to authorize with Pundit
    authorize @project
  end
```

For context I am running Searchkick and acts_as_tenant (hence the account_id reference).  The `set_model` is failing in all tests across my app.  Restarted the db and ES.  I even fired up the console in test mode and all the proper data is in there (even Project with id = 980190962).

As I mentioned this was working - unfortunately I can't really see at which point I broke this.

Anything obvious jump out to anyone?

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Project with 'id'=980190962 [WHERE "projects"."account_id" = $1] indicates that the project doesn't belong to the account being used to test.

Comment: I made a dummy test with `puts Project.find(980190962).inspect` and `get project_url(@project)`.  The first returns the Project the second the same error as above.  I am questing the acts_as_tenant gem at this point.  May try rolling back to an old commit to see what I broke.

Comment: Tracing it back to some bizarre account model fixture changes.  Very strange.  Will post an answer once I sort this out.